# Why does it represent change in velocity?

Tags: vectors, velocity, faq

[image]

In the above image a particle goes with velocity $v_0$ at some direction and then in an another direction where its velocity is represented by $v$. Both are same in magnitude but their direction is different and this can also be represented by a triangle. In this case the other side of the triangle is the change in velocity. But why?

Comment: I don't understand your difficulty. The vector diagram tells you the third vector is the difference in velocity.

Comment: Seems to me that I know everything but my brain is arguing with this.

Comment: @BobD I have no problem with the magnitude or direction of the vectors. I just want to know why will the third side represent it?

Comment: Velocities are vectors. A change in velocity is the addition or subtraction of vectors. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Scalar subtraction:**

Forget vectors for the minute.

5 - 4 = 1

The difference between 5 and 4, is 1

Aka,  the number I need to add onto 4, in order to get 5, is 1.

**Vector subtraction:**

This is the same with vectors

$$\vec{v} - \vec{v_{0}}$$ by definition, is the vector I need to add onto $\vec{v_{0}}$ in order to  get to $\vec{v}$

Put in a mathematical form

$$\vec{v}_{0} + (\vec{v} - \vec{v_{0}}) = \vec{v}$$

"The vector I need to add onto $\vec{v_{0}}$ in order to  get to v" is just another way of saying "the change in velocity"

**Why does it form a triangle?**

Well if $\vec{v} - \vec{v_{0}}$ by definition, is the vector I need to add onto $\vec{v_{0}}$ in order to  get to $\vec{v}$, then starting at $\vec{v_{0}}$ and adding that vector to $\vec{v_{0}}$,  should reach the the same as vector $\vec{v}$. So should obviously point to the same location, aka a triangle

Or use the classic phrase "line the vectors head to toe to find the addition"

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with vector addition? Check out [Vector Addition on Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorAddition.html).

Here we want the change in velocity, $\Delta$**v** such that **v** = **v**$_0$ + $\Delta$**v** or in other words what do we add to **v**$_0$ in order to get **v**. From you diagram we add **v** - **v**$_0$ so **v** - **v**$_0$ is $\Delta$**v**, the change in velocity.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that subtracting with a vector corresponds to adding the opposite vector (the same vector pointing the other way).

So, instead of trying to subtract $v_0$ from $v$, then just add $-v_0$ to $v$. And think of these vectors as paths you are moving along.

After having done this addition, you will see that you end up at a distance and direction from your starting point that exactly corresponds to the difference vector $v-v_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the two vectors $\vec v_0 $ and $\vec v$ as shown.  Let $\vec r$ be the vector added to $\vec v_0$ to form $\vec v$: $\vec v_0 + \vec r = \vec v$.  Then, $\vec r = \vec v - \vec v_0$.

Comment: Don't you mean v - v$_0$?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I made the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the direction of the vectors what is vector $\vec v_0$ added to vector $(\vec v-\vec v_0)$  equal to?

$\ v_0+(\vec v-\vec v_0)=\vec v$

Thus $(\vec v-\vec v_0)$ is the “final” velocity minus the “initial” velocity, ie the change in velocity.

Comment: My question was about why it was $\vec v  - \vec v_0$?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The sum of the vectors is equal to the zero vector ( closed loop) thus

[image]

What is $~\Delta\vec v$ for this configuration?

[image]